# JQuery call an animation function when first ends

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, styles

I'm trying to make a step by step animation of a div in JQuery. I call the animation with a click, then the second with double click, then third...

My problem is that they overlay. If I start double clicking the div it starts both first and second animations at once and it goes crazy. So I'm trying to only let it activate the dblclick once the first function stopped.

I tried to make it work with *if else* and *.is* selector and it doesn't work.

```
$(document).ready( function (){
    $(".group").one("click", showInfo);
})

function showInfo(){

    $(this).stop().animate({height: "260px"});

    $(".group").one("dblclick", showMoreInfo);

})

function showMoreInfo(){

    $(this).stop().animate({height: "0px"});

    $(".group").one("click", showInfo);

})
```

Comment: This is tricky to diagnose without seeing a working example, but try putting the `.grupo` event handler in the callback of the `animate` call

Comment: Post your html/css too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery [animate](https://api.jquery.com/animate/) has a complete callback, you can use it to set the next animation:

```js
function showInfo(){
    $(this).stop().animate({height: "260px"}, function () { 
        $(".group").unbind("click");
        $(".group").on("dblclick", showMoreInfo);
    });
}

function showMoreInfo(){
    $(this).stop().animate({height: "20px"}, function() {
        $(".group").unbind("dblclick");
        $(".group").on("click", showInfo);
    });
}

$(document).ready( function (){
   $(".group").on("click", showInfo);
});
```

```css
.group {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="group"></div>
```

And [unbind](https://api.jquery.com/unbind/) the previous event in that callbacks.

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked perfectly and I understood the callback. :)